# google dashboard show google map api hit from desktop not from apk - cordova and google map issue

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps, phonegap-plugins, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to hit google map api from apk but google developer console not showing any hit but if i am trying it via browser its showing hits ( cordoava and google map issue )

I added :

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
```

In AndroidManifest.xml as well

AndroidManifest.xml - http://jsfiddle.net/HGJb3/301/

Comment: Hit means what describe more ? Also post your whole *manifest code*.

Comment: hit means i am getting latitude and longitude etc.

Comment: Show me your whole *manifest code please*.

Comment: There is not showing any *meta tag* in above *fiddle manifest* please post *full manifest*. also not any *permissions* related to map.

Comment: i just removed the mata data but <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/> is the meta data key.

Comment: Try with this in your *meta tag*  using `android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"`. And make sure you generated *API_KEY* from developer console. And also *enabled google maps api*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122645/discussion-between-supersaiyan-and-jaydroider).